# What foods can increase penis length and girth?

Tags: nutrition, penis

Are there any foods that can naturally increase the length and girth of my penis?

Some food I can think about are:

1. Milk
2. Steak
3. Eggs
4. Basil
5. Broccoli

I'm not looking for like 5 extra inches, just maybe 1 more inch would be fantastic.

Comment: I don't think any food can start growth of body parts. Milk won't help you grow 2 inches taller either once you stopped growing.

Comment: http://www.express.co.uk/life-style/health/750930/mircopenis-cure-update

Answer (score 14):

After full sexual development is complete (usually the teens for most males), penis enlargement is impossible. Anyone who tells you otherwise is a liar and is probably trying to sell you something.

http://www.webmd.com/men/guide/penis-enlargement-does-it-work#1

> "I think there isn't a guy in the world who hasn't wished his penis
>   were an inch or two longer," says Michael O'Leary, MD, professor of
>   urologic surgery at Harvard Medical School and a urologist at Brigham
>   and Women's Hospital in Boston.
>
> However, after more than a century of generally dubious and sometimes
>   lunatic penis enlargement attempts, there's still not much you can do.
>   Sure, there are lots and lots of supposed options out there -- penis
>   pills, creams, brutal stretching exercises, horrific-looking devices,
>   and penis surgery. Almost none of it works. The few approaches that
>   can work often have modest benefits and serious side effects. How
>   serious? In some cases, erectile dysfunction-serious.
>
> "Trust me, if I knew of a way to safely and effectively increase penis
>   size, I'd be a billionaire," O'Leary tells WebMD. "But I don't. Nobody
>   does."

Comment: Somehow I would add that enlargement is in almost all cases unnecessary; unlike having the equipment in 'working order'. As the perceived necessity for such a question is routed in wrong beliefs or body dysmorphism there are treatments available that work: education and psychotherapy.